# arc land fails with EXCEPTION: (CommandException) Command failed with error #1

Tags: git, bash, phabricator

I'm trying to land a local branch with the remote origin branch via Phabricator. 
When I try to land I get the following error

```
[2015-10-07 13:47:25] EXCEPTION: (CommandException) Command failed with error #1!
COMMAND
git pull --ff-only --no-stat

STDOUT
(empty)

STDERR
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Password for 'http://xxxxx@localgitrepository': Invalid argument
```

It was working well with my old laptop, but I recently switched to a new one, however arc diff works, but landing doesn't. Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your old computer, you probably had ssh setup so you would clone from ssh://git@localgitrepository.  Because this is scripted and it is encountering a password prompt, it is unable to give the password.  You have 2 options:

1. Change your remote URL to use ssh `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@localgitrepository`
2. Setup a user for Arcanist to connect as and set the username and password in the .arcconfig file. ([More information can be found here](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_new_project/#advanced-arcconfig).)